# How could new items be saved in a dat file which are added by the user?

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

There's a dictionary with 3 pairs of fruits in 2 languages. One of them is not correct in English (pomme - aple) which can be fixed by user. Also, user can add new words to the dictionary in 2 languages. User can quit the dictionary if doesn’t want to add new fruit or fix the wrong one. 
The new or fixed words should be saved in a dat file, but the file remains empty :( 
It’s a homework and I have to solve this problem with shelve, but I don’t know how.
Here is my attempt:

```
import shelve
store = shelve.open("fruits.dat")
try:
    mydict = store["allfruits"]
except:
    mydict = {"pomme" : "aple", "poire" : "pear", "cerise" : "cherry"}

mydict = {"pomme" : "aple", "poire" : "pear", "cerise" : "cherry"}
while True: 
    answer=input("Write a fruits name ")
    if answer == "pomme":
        print(mydict["pomme"])
        answer1=input("Would you like to change it? ")
        if answer1 == "yes":
            newworld=input("What's that? ")
            mydict2 = {"pomme" : newworld}
            mydict.update(mydict2)
            anotherfruit=input("Thx. Are you interested in another fruits name? ")
            if anotherfruit=="yes":
                continue
            else:
                print("Bye")
                break
        else:
            print("Bye")
            break
    elif answer not in mydict:
        adding=input("It's not in there. Would you like to add? ")
        if adding == "yes":
            newworld1=input("How is it in English? ")
            mydict3 = {answer : newworld1}
            mydict.update(mydict3)
            anotherfruit=input("Thx. Are you interested in another fruits name? ")
            if anotherfruit=="yes":
                continue
            else:
                print(mydict)
                break
        else:
            print("Bye")
            break

store["allfruits"] = mydict
store.sync()
store.close()
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work at all" what doesn't work?  I've checked your code, and while I would make a number of suggestions for improving it, it seems to basically work as intended.

Comment: The only major bug I can see is right at the beginning you redefined `mydict` even after reading it from the shelve file.

Comment: 0


I fixed the description: the dat file remains empty and after running again the code the previously added fruits names disappear from the dictionary.

Comment: See my previous comment:  Your dictionary is being updated fine.  Try just running `db = shelve.open('fruits.dat'); print(db['allfruits'])`.  You'll see that the file is not empty.  At the beginning of your code you're redefining `mydict` immediately after reading it from the shelve db, giving the appearance that your changes weren't saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here -->

```
try:
    mydict = store["allfruits"]
except:
    mydict = {"pomme" : "aple", "poire" : "pear", "cerise" : "cherry"}

mydict = {"pomme" : "aple", "poire" : "pear", "cerise" : "cherry"}
while True:
    ...
```

You try to read `mydict` from the DB with `mydict = store['allfruits']`.  If that fails (in the `except:` statement) you assign `mydict` a default value.  That part's fine.

But then immediately after you assign `mydict = { ... }` again overriding what you just read from the database.

Comment: Thank you very much!